# PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

I'm trying to call the budget API using a service account and a key file but I get this error:

> PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission

### My Code

```js
async function listBillingAccounts() {
    const [account] = await client.getBillingAccount({ name: `billingAccounts/${BILLING_ACCOUNT_ID}` });
    console.info({ account });
}
listBillingAccounts();
```

### My CLI Setup

```sh
gcloud config set project my-project-id
```

### Environment Variables as Mentioned in [Their Docs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production):

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS | path\to\gcp-credentials.json |
| GCP_PROJECT | my-project-id |

### Service Account Setup

When I go to https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=my-project-id, it shows the service account in the table:

| Member | Name | Role | Inheritance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| owner-75@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com | owner | Owner | my-project-id |

I don't know what to do next.

Comment: The `Owner` role is a legacy role that existed before IAM. This role does not have all permissions. This role does have the power to add roles that it does not have. Billing Accounts are not part of a project. They are linked to a project. Go to your Billing Account -> Account Management. In the right side panel click Add Member. Link to a Google Video on Billing Permissions: https://www.jhanley.com/videolabs/Google-Cloud-Billing/#9

Comment: Wow! That solved it for me! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for the contribution @JohnHanley. Very nice site and great stuff. I will dig into it.

Comment: Thank you. I am updating my Billing Videolab today with two new sections at the end. FYI: For the latest on GCP Billing Features: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/release-notes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `owner` role of a project does not grant you the necessary permissions to view billing account information.

According to the [API documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/billing/latest/v1.CloudBillingClient.html#getBillingAccount) when they describe the `getBillingAccount` operation:

> Gets information about a billing account. The current authenticated user must be a viewer of the billing account.

You can grant the viewer of the billing account permission at the organization or billing account level. Please, see the relevant [docs](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-access?hl=en#overview-of-cloud-billing-roles-in-cloud-iam).